# How to disable test parallel execution for all tests marked with custom Facts in XUnit.Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, xunit

We have an open source project for running remote XUnit.Net tests. The feature is that the body of the test is designed to run on a remote process and the results are serialized back to visual studio. The project can be found here.

https://github.com/Weingartner/XUnitRemote

For example a test might be like

```
    [SampleProcessFact]
    public void OutOfProcess()
    {
        _Output.WriteLine("Process name: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        Assert.Equal(1,1);
    }
```

**SampleProcessFact** is a custom attribute declared so.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
[XunitTestCaseDiscoverer("XUnitRemote.Test.SampleProcessFactDiscoverer", "XUnitRemote.Test")]
public class SampleProcessFactAttribute : FactAttribute { }


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
[XunitTestCaseDiscoverer("XUnitRemote.Test.ScheduledSampleProcessFactDiscoverer", "XUnitRemote.Test")]
public class ScheduledSampleProcessFactAttribute : FactAttribute { }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
[XunitTestCaseDiscoverer("XUnitRemote.Test.SampleProcessTheoryDiscoverer", "XUnitRemote.Test")]
public class SampleProcessTheoryAttribute : TheoryAttribute { }
```

See https://github.com/Weingartner/XUnitRemote/blob/master/XUnitRemote.Test/XUnit.cs#L26 for source code.

However we would like an option so that if I tag my test case as **SampleProcessFact** then the test runner will only run the tests sequentially.

I am aware that I can tag all my test cases with **TestCollection(string id)** and it should prevent sequential running but this should be encapsulated in the **SampleProcessFact** tag if possible. This should work across all test cases in all assemblies.

My question only relates to the firing off of tests from visual studio. The remote part works fine but visual studio is calling our remote test case engine in parallel for all the tests.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We made a checkin to our project that solved the problem.

https://github.com/Weingartner/XUnitRemote/commit/565e1dfb55f65ff0612afa40bc5d076c69bb739c

The general solution was to intercept the **ITestMethod** instance within XUnitRemoteTestCaseDiscoverer::Discover and rewrite the UniqueId of it's test collection.

```
    public IEnumerable<IXunitTestCase> Discover(ITestFrameworkDiscoveryOptions discoveryOptions, ITestMethod testMethod, IAttributeInfo factAttribute)
    {
        if(CollectionId.HasValue)
            testMethod = WrapTestMethod(testMethod, CollectionId.Value);

        if (!Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.Equals(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_ExePath), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            yield return new XUnitRemoteTestCase(_DiagnosticMessageSink, discoveryOptions.MethodDisplayOrDefault(), testMethod, _Id, _ExePath);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var testCase in _DefaultTestCaseDiscoverer.Discover(discoveryOptions, testMethod, factAttribute))
            {
                yield return _TestCaseConverter(testCase);
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
    private ITestMethod WrapTestMethod(ITestMethod testMethod, Guid uniqueId)
    {
        var testClass = testMethod.TestClass;
        var testCollection = testClass.TestCollection;
        testCollection = new TestCollection
            (testCollection.TestAssembly, testCollection.CollectionDefinition, testCollection.DisplayName)
        {
            UniqueID = uniqueId
        };
        testClass = new TestClass(testCollection, testClass.Class);
        testMethod = new TestMethod(testClass, testMethod.Method);
        return testMethod;
    }
```